# Ajax request to upload image and save in server

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, firebase

I am trying to save an image in server location following is my HTML code:

HTML code:

```
<form>
 <input type="file" accept="image/*"/>
</form>
```

Javascript

```
        var file    = document.querySelector('input[type=file]').files[0];
        var reader  = new FileReader();
        if (file) {
            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        }
        reader.addEventListener("load", function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'http://localhost/MyProject/src/images',
                data: {filename: file.filename, data: file.data},
                succes: function(response){
                    alert(response.responseText);
                },
                error: function(error) {
                    alert(error.responseText);
                }
            });
        }, false);
```

The success method of ajax is being called but on debugging I found that file.data is undefined. What variable should be used instead of file.data ?I need the uploaded image to be saved in my server

**EDIT**

I followed the answer in the mentioned duplicate question here is the new code

HTML:

```
<form id='uploadForm' enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input name="file" type="file" id="fileName" />                 
    <button ng-click="signIn()">Upload</button>
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
var fileInput = document.getElementById('fileName');
        var file = fileInput.files[0];
        var form = document.getElementById('uploadForm');
        var formdata = new FormData(form);
        formdata.append('file', file)
            //Save image in serverBase
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'http://localhost/MyProject/src/images',
                    // Form data
                    data: formdata,
                    // Tell jQuery not to process data or worry about content-type
                    // You *must* include these options!
                    cache: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    processData: false,
                    success: function(response){
                        alert(response);
                    },
                    error: function(error) {
                        alert(error.responseText);
                    }
                });
```

Using the above code my image is not getting saved in the mentioned 'http://localhost/MyProject/src/images' directory , although the ajax call is successful but the alert I get in response is some HTML code .Not sure whats happening. Any idea?

**EDIT**

On browsing some of the questions like this [How to store uploaded file into server path using either javascript or jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32842207/how-to-store-uploaded-file-into-server-path-using-either-javascript-or-jquery)

It seems javascript being a client side scripting language isnt enough to store image on server path. I am using firebase for communicating with database . Do I have to include some other language too just to save data on my server?Does firebase have provisions to help me with the same?

Comment: When sending binary data in an AJAX request you should use a `FormData` object. See the duplicate question for more information

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan That does answer how to send the ajax request , but i need to write the image in my server , currently I followed the answer in the duplicate question but with success ajax call but I am not the image is not uploaded on the server instead I see some HTML code returned in the response

Comment: Firebase provides cloud storage where I can store the uploaded pics, so I dont need to use any other language , firebase APIs would do the job for me thanks